# Use mix of "dates" (months and weeks) in Power BI graph ledgend

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I am working on transforming an excel graph to power bi to be able to use same datasets etc.

The Excel file is using many different calculations and pivots to in the end present a graph showing the last 4 weeks and the 6 last finalized months.
Weeks are previoud 4 weeks, not including this week, and a month is finalized 14 days into the new month.
So, this means that the weeks and months might overlap.

Is there a way to duplicate into Power BI? Maybe using group by in different ways to make week and month data and then doing calculations on tha? Any ideas how to start with it?

Thanks for help,

Edit: Have added some example data, but only in pivot format since I can not attach the excel file.

Example graph:
[image]

Example data:
[image]

[image]

And above is combined to via formulas:
[image]

Comment: You have not provided enough information or sample data for anyone to properly help you

Comment: @horseyride Hi, I can not find how to actually attach an example excel, but have added how the data looks like (after adding them in pivot tables. If you have how to attach, please tell me and Ill do it.

Comment: @Akire you may need to share database as in Powerbi we handled data with columns not pivot data.